# Html.ActionLink onclick JavaScript function is not invoked and name of function is corrupted in output HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I looked at other question: [how to call javascript function in html.actionlink in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856071/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) showing how to add `onclick` to `@Html.ActionLink` but in my case function I assigned to `onclick` is never invoked.

I tried these action links:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Call number", "Call", new { id = Model.Id, number = Model.CellNumber, onclick = "javascript:alert(a);" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
<p> @Html.ActionLink("Call number »", "Call", new { id = Model.Id, number = Model.SecondaryPhoneNumber, onclick = "javascript:Call();" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
```

and the function looks like:

```
<script>
    function Call(){
        alert("BLA");
    }
</script>
```

but no alert is shown in both cases(first and second button). Besides that action link wroks.

**Question:** What I did wrong?

EDIT:

Action links in html look like that and the look corrupted:`onclick=Call%28%29%3B`

```
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Person/Call/7?number=113-456-789&amp;onclick=alert%28a%29%3B">Call Cell Phone</a></p>
<p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Person/Call/7?number=98873213&amp;onclick=Call%28%29%3B">Call Client&#39;s Secondary Number &#187;</a></p>
```

and the function looks like it should:

```
<script>
    function Call(){
        alert("BLA");
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: you dont need to add `javascript:` to an onclick. You would only do this for a `href` target on a link. e.g. either `onclick="Call()"` or `href="javascript:Call()"`. You can see this in the answer to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856071/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc]

Comment: @Rhumborl This is the answer I used before I asked question here and did not work. Please see my edit it looks like that html browser sees gets something like that: `onclick=Call%28%29%3B`

Comment: @JLRishe I posted HTML in EDIT at the bottom of OP it seems the name of function is corrupted there. I added link to the answer I used to solve the problem before I asked question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add onclick handler in wrong place. You must put it in `Html Attributes` block instead `Route values`.
Try it:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Call number", "Call", new { id = Model.Id, number = Model.CellNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", onclick = "alert('a');" })</p>
```