# Calling jQuery method after controller method in Html.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got a Bootstrap modal window that has an ActionLink to call a method in the controller and to do stuff:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Process Data", "ProcessData", "Controller", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

However, I want to do it so that when the user presses this ActionLink (the Save Changes button), I want the modal to close automatically after they press it.

Is there a way to directly call another jQuery/Javascript method once ProcessData finishes executing? This also isn't a POST method if it matters.

Comment: You may write Js function onclick event to close the model. How are you calling controller method? ajax?

Comment: It sounds like maybe the call to ProcessData should be called in an Ajax call rather than an Actionlink.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856071/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below executes the **someFunction** function before the Controller/Action

```
@Html.ActionLink("linky", "action", "controller", new { onclick = "someFunction();"})
```

---

So if you want to control the flow you can use ajax, declare the button

```
<input type="button" id="btnAction" />
```

Then assign an action to your **click** event

```
$('#btnAction').click(someFunction);
```

And now implement your function using **ajax**

```
$.ajax({
            url: url/controller/action',
            type: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
            success: function (data) {
                //HERE YOUR CODE IN YOUR CONTROLLER WAS EXECUTED/FINISHED AND 
                //YOU CAN CALL YOUR JS FUNCTION

                yourSECONDfunction();
            }
        });
```