# ActionLink to pass a input value from a different table cell to controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I'm working in MVC.
I have a table with a bunch of rows. One cell contains an 'Order' button, and a different cell contains a numeric input where the user can specify the quantity of the item he wants to buy? How do I pass through the quantity value in my ActionLink from the input cell? The issue here is not in finding a text value, but rather finding the text value of a specific row

[image]

**Table Cells**

```
        <td><input id="itemQuantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="@item.QuantityInStock" size="10" class="universalWidth"/></td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Order", "OrderTuckShop", new { id = item.IngredientId, quanity = ???}, new { @class = "btn btn-success universalWidth" })</td>
```

**Method Call**

```
public ActionResult OrderTuckShop(Guid? id, int quantity)
```

Comment: @S.Akbari, how?

Comment: Check duplicate answers.

Comment: @S.Akbari this is not the same since my text value should come from the same row as the button click. My trouble is in finding the correct input on the row. The answer you marked as duplicate does not have anything to to with table or cell values

Comment: The Action link helper is processed at server, so you wont be able to get the value of the text box and generate the link accordingly, because the page itself is not rendered in the browser. A work around will be attaching an onclick event to the ActionLink, then within the function you can find the value of the text box and generate another http get call. Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856071/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the value of the textbox in your `ActionLink()` method because its razor code, and that is parsed on the server before its sent to the client. In order to respond to client side events you need to use javascript/jquery.

Create a manual link and add the `IngredientId` as a `data-` attribute and add an additional class name to use as a selector

```
<td>
    <a href="#" data-id="@item.IngredientId" class="order btn btn-success universalWidth">Order</a>
</td>
```

In addition, remove the `id="itemQuantity"` in the input (duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html) and add a class name as a selector

```
<input class="quantity" type="number" ... />
```

Then include the following script to read the value of the input and make a redirect

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("OrderTuckShop")';
$('.order).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').val();
    location.href = baseUrl + '?id=' + id + '&quanity=' + quanity;
});
```

However, the name of the method suggests you perhaps should be making a POST, not a GET?