# How to call javascript after ASP.NET MVC controller method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been tasked with resolving a few bugs on a Razor page.

I know it is ASP.NET MVC, it uses the .NET Framework 4.5.2, and I suspect the version of MVC this project is using is 5.2 because I found this in the **Web.config** file:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

The `@Html.BeginForm()` is used without parameters and has an `<input type="submit" />`:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"" />
```

It will call either method **RetailActivity()** or **RetailActivity(MyModel model)** in the **AdminController.cs**.

The documentation for [Html.BeginForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) shows several overloads that I have no experience with.

The HTML has a basic "wait" image that shows while the Database Server is retrieving data:

```html
<div id="loadingDiv" style="position:fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%">
    <img src="~/Images/wait.gif" />
    <br />Loading. Please Wait.
</div>
```

In Javascript, the "wait" DIV shows when the DropDown lists are populated with the AJAX calls.

```js
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $loading.show();
    })
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $loading.hide();
    });
});

function getDealers(e) {
    let dealership = document.getElementById("DealerID");
    let value = $(dealership).val();
    $.get("@Url.Action("GetDealers", "Admin")?region=" + value, function (res) {
        var markup = "";
        for (var i = 0; (res != null) && (i < res.length); i++) {
            markup += '<option value=' + res[i].Value + '>' + res[i].Text + '</option>';
        }
        $('#DealerID').prop('disabled', false);
        $("#DealerID").html(markup).show();
    });
}
```

Those are working, but I want a way to show and hide the div when the main **FORM SUBMIT** is triggered.

I've seen that I can put Javascript in the [Html.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2):

[how to call javascript function in html.actionlink in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2856071/153923)

...but I don't see a way to do that in the *Html.BeginForm* part of Razor.

So, I edited my *Html.BeginForm* so that I could manually handle the call in Javascript:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
//
   <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" onclick="formSearch();" />
```

So far, I've tried `formSearch()` two (2) ways:

```js
function formSearch_old() {
    var value = $('#DealerID').val();
    var text = $('#DealerID :selected').text();
    console.log('Inside formSearch() routine: value=' + value + ', text=' + text);
    $loading.show();
    console.log('showing spinner');
    $.get("@Url.Action("RetailActivity", "Admin")?model=" + Model);
    $loading.hide();
    console.log('hiding spinner');
    $('#DealerID').val(value);
    console.log('DealerID set to ' + value);
}

function formSearch() {
    var value = $('#DealerID').val();
    var text = $('#DealerID :selected').text();
    history.go(-1);
    console.log('Inside formSearch() routine: value=' + value + ', text=' + text);
    $loading.show();
    console.log('showing spinner');
    $("#myForm").submit();
    $loading.hide();
    console.log('hiding spinner');
    $('#DealerID').val(value);
    console.log('DealerID set to ' + value);
}
```

In the old version, this line executes immediately:

```js
$.get("@Url.Action("RetailActivity", "Admin")?model=" + Model;
```

That doesn't work because `Model` is undefined. I tried using `@Model` instead, but that just provided the fully qualified string name of the class.

The current version uses this line:

```js
$("#myForm").submit();
```

It executes fine. In the Console Window, I have this data:

```
Inside formSearch() routine: value=159200, text=Dri-Port Marine
RetailActivity:222 showing spinner
RetailActivity:226 hiding spinner
RetailActivity:228 DealerID set to 159200
```

But, it finishes running immediately while my form is still waiting for the Database Server to return the data.

So that is what I've tried.

### Should I fix one of the Javascript `formSearch()` methods or use an overload for the Razor `@Html.BeginForm()` call?

I hope this isn't too complicated. It took hours to write out.

Comment: Am I correct in saying you want to display the loading div when the form is submitted? What happens after the form is submitted do you move to a different view or stay on the same one?

Comment: @Macilquham, yes. And I stay on the same page. Submit fills the HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set it up in my project, this code is not really mine, but I can't remember the source. Use the following JavaScript function and modify it for your own purpose:

```
function disableSecondCLick (ctl, msg, form = null, isThisAForm = true) {
  const isFormValid = $(form).valid()
  if (isFormValid) {
    $(ctl).prop('disabled', true).text(msg);
    $('.submit-progress').removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible');
    $('body').addClass('progress-body-bg');
    if (isThisAForm) {
      $(form).submit();
    }
    //I encase my form controls inside a <fieldset> to disable them during submit. 
    //This prevents the user from messing with them during the process.
    $('fieldset').prop('disabled', true); 
  }
  return true;
}
```

This is a function I use whenever I need to disable a button and display a progress div. Then in your submit button add an onclick event handler and call it as shown:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="form1" onclick="disableSecondCLick(this,'Submitting...','#form1',true);">Submit</button>
```

In your CSS file add the following class to darken the background when you're showing the progress div:

```
.progress-body-bg {
    background-color: lightgray;
    opacity: .5;
}
```