# JSON String as Javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to define a pure JSON string as an argument in a Javascript function.

Below is the way I want to define it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="js_func('arg_1', 'arg_2', '{"key": "value"}'); return false">Link</a>
```

Firebug gives me an error alert: unterminated string literal, even when I escape the double-quotes on the JSON string.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: whats with the `return false`.  can you put more than one command into an event like that?  and no semicolon?  im not 100% here so sorry if this is acceptable

Comment: @jon, see [HTML: What's the effect of adding 'return false' to an onclick event ?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/html-whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event).

Comment: @Matt - come on sending me that link is kind of condescending.  I know returning fales stops the behavior that would otherwise occur.  what is the point here?  Why not skip the hyperlink reference at all?

Comment: is it not allowed to have an anchor with no href attribute?  is that the point?

Comment: @jon, if it seemed condescending, I'm sorry.  It wasn't meant to be.  You can have an empty `href`, or you can use "#".  Without `return false` (or equivalent), the first will cause a reload, and the second will cause a jump to the top of the page.

Comment: link with no href causes reload?  ok thats what i didnt get sorry for confusion.  without understanding that the blanket `return false` seemed dumb

Comment: @jon, well, a link with an empty href.  An `a` element with no href is an anchor.

Comment: aaah right. so the need for that `href` and `return false` instead of just dropping the `href` attribute is so the text maintains appearance of a link. correct?

Comment: Matthew is absolutely correct about the use of href attribute and return false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `&quot;` for your double quotes, <strike>then in `js_func()`, replace them with actual double quote characters (`"`) before evaluating your JSON string.</strike> (thanks for the demo Matthew, I updated your fiddle with the example from the question:)

http://jsfiddle.net/brillyfresh/kdwRy/1/

Comment: The unescaping is already done by the browser - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdwRy/).

Comment: brillyfresh essentially has the answer to the question here, with the correction from Matthew (that no unescape is necessary on the JS end).  The reason Chuck is getting the error is because the browser sees the " before key and thinks it's the end of the onclick attribute's value.

Comment: Thanks brillyfresh, this worked for me. Thanks for Matthew as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

simply defining the link as `<a href="#" onclick="js_func('arg_1', 'arg_2', {key: 'value1'}); return false;">Link</a>` works fine. JSON is valid JavaScript, you don't need to enclose it in ''s.
I also suggest to use an EventListener (`element.addEventListener()`), this makes the html cleaner and would reduce this problem to nothing.

Comment: Well, his code was attempting to pass a JSON string.  You're passing a JavaScript object generated from a object literal.  There's a difference.  Usually, you would want the literal here, but not necessarily.  You're right that using `addEventListener` could greatly simplify things.

Comment: i thought he may had the believe that every argument given in onclick has to be "stringified" - thats certainly not the case and hence my answer.

Answer (score -1):

ryou are either trying to pass the parsed object or pass a string

```
Object: onclick="js_func(arg_1, arg_2, {'key': 'value'});"

String: on_click="js_func('arg_1', 'arg_2', '{\"key\": \"value\"}'); return false"
```

All I've got handy to test is firebug interpreter but both worked fine for me.

```
>>>>'{\"key\": \"value\"}'
"{"key": "value"}"
>>>> {'key': 'value'}
Object {key="value"}
```

(I don't mean to presume whether `arg_1` and `arg_2` are strings or variable names, and it doesnt matter.  just did the same thing as with the JSON)

Comment: `return false` prevents the event from propagating, thus preventing the browser from handling the click as it normally would.

Comment: what is 'normally would' in this case?  it does it on every click.  when does the link actually get followed?

Comment: The normal behavior is to follow the link ("#" in this case).

Comment: but EVERY click returns false.  in what case does that actually happen?

Comment: @jon, the link never gets followed.  It's essentially pretending to be a link, while really only triggering JavaScript.

Comment: right.  so my point was just to lose the `href` attribute instead.  but ive since realized the text will not resemble a link without it

Comment: This won't solve the problem.  What you suggest here would apply if he were binding the event IN javascript, but he's not - he's binding it in the HTML tag.