# form resetting in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reset a form with a confirm window.  My html looks like:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="showReset();"/>
```

then for my javascript:

```
function doReset() {
    var formElements = document1.form1.elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
        formElements[i].value = "";
        if (formElements[i].checked) {
            formElements[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}

function showReset() {
    if (window.confirm("Do you really want to reset the form?")) {
        doReset();
    }
}
```

When I hit cancel on the confirm window, the form still gets reset and I'm not sure why.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, the point is to bypass the default behavior and use your function instead.  You can prevent the default button action by adding a return false to the showReset() function.

```
function showReset(e) {
    if (window.confirm("Do you really want to reset the form?")) {
        doReset();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, make sure the onclick handler returns the results of showReset:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="return showReset();"/>
```

Alternatively, if you want default browser behavior and just want a confirm dialog, why not use a confirm only?  Like so:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="return window.confirm('Do you really want to reset the form?');"/>
```

This is just a "what to do", but if you want to get more info, there's some good info in these threads:

- [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)
- [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event)

Answer (score 2):

It still gets reset because your input type is reset. Make that button or something and just use the form's reset method, like this:

```
document.form1.reset();
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it :

```
var r=confirm("Do you really want to reset the form?");  
if(r==true){  
//Reset logic  
}else{  
//Dont reset logic  
}
```