# Javascript in HTML: when to use semi-colons, when to return false?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following examples of Javascript attributes in HTML elements:

```
<input type="button" onclick="somceFunc()" />
<input type="button" onclick="somceFunc();" />
<input type="button" onclick="somceFunc(); return false;" />
```

When should one end the `someFunc()` call with a semi-colon, and when should the semi-colon be eliminated? Also, when should one end the attribute with a call to `return false;`?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you should never end with `false` - it doesn't do anything. (You might be thinking of `return false;`)

Comment: that's not a colon. It's a semicolon.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is best practice to end all the function calls with a semicolon.  And like Juhana said you should use return false;  This will disable whatever the default action is (ie return false for onsubmit would disable the form from performing its default action)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When should one end the someFunc() call with a colon, and when should the colon be eliminated?

That's a semi-colon. Always end expressions with one. Automatic semi-colon insertion has enough gotchas that you are better off just avoiding it.

> Also, when should one end the attribute with a call to `false`?

`false` is a literal, not a function, you can't call it.

The usage in that example does absolutely nothing.

If you were to `return false` from an intrinsic event attribute (like `onclick`) then you would stop the default action of the control from firing. e.g. a link would not be followed. A button has no default action though.

Intrinsic event attributes should be avoided in favour of [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Four... frickin... seconds... You beat me =_=

Comment: Thank you. The Wikipedia link is great.

Answer (score 2):

**SEMI**-colons are optional in JavaScript, but it's always a good idea to include them to avoid nasty surprises, such as what happens if you try to do this:

```
return
  {
    a:1,
    b:2
  };
```

As for the `false`, it alone does nothing. You want to **`return`**`false` when you want to stop the default click action from happening (usually only matters on links or form buttons).

Comment: Thank you Kolink. That is an interesting example for the lack of semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

> Semicolons serve to separate statements from each other,

It is good practice to use semicolon after a function call or any JavaScript statement.

For 'false' statement :

```
<input type="button" onclick="somceFunc(); false;" />
```

This is wrong approach. Either you should call `return false`
Well, `return false` is call to prevent the action to be called.