# Target=Blank link with OnClick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

Why the TARGET _BLANK parameter does not work, when there is onClick parameter? 
The onlick is google event script.  When I add onclick to this link, it opens inside the frameset.

```
<a target=_blank href="externalwwwlink" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Link', 'aaa');return false;">OPEN </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return `false` here:

```
onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Link', 'aaa'); return false;"
```

so it prevents usual behaviour (bubling of click event). It is very common way to prevent standard action (redirecting by reference, or submitting a form).

Answer (score 1):

Your `onClick` handler has a `return false` at the end, which is an [old way of telling the browser to **stop handling** the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event). The browser will not open the link, and in your case, not open the href in a new (blank) window/tab.

Remove the `return false;` at the end of the onClick so the browser knows it can go on.