# I want to verify in JavaScript that my required fields are not blank

Tags: javascript, validation

Hopefully this is basic JavaScript and the answer is easy since I am new at this. I just want to make sure all required fields are not blank before the user can proceed. In my `<form>` `action` `=` `payment.php` and the submit button contains `onclick="insert();"` When child_name is left blank, it just proceeds to the next page rather than alerting. Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function insert() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XLMHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }



        cn1 = 'child_name'+document.getElementById('child_name').value;
        ag2 = 'age'+document.getElementById('age').value;
        hm3 = 'hometown'+document.getElementById('hometown').value;
        bg4 = 'boy_girl'+document.getElementById('boy_girl').value;
        fn5 = 'first_name'+document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        ln6 = 'last_name'+document.getElementById('last_name').value;
        email = 'email'+document.getElementById('email').value;
        ad8 = 'address1'+document.getElementById('address1').value;
        ad9 = 'address2'+document.getElementById('address2').value;
        ct10 = 'city'+document.getElementById('city').value;
        st11 = 'state'+document.getElementById('state').value;
        zp12 = 'zip'+document.getElementById('zip').value;

        if (cn1.equals("")) {


        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'payment.php', true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(cn1&ag2&hm3&bg4&fn5&ln6&email$ad8&ad9&ct10&st11&zp12); 
        } else {
        alert ("Please enter all required fields.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean "JavaScript", not "Java", right?

Comment: What I understood is, you want us to correct your code, right?

Comment: The binary `&` operator does not concatenate strings. Also, you forgot the `=`s and to `encodeURIComponent` your values.

Comment: Where's the code that calls this function? What does that look like?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues here:

```
cn1 = 'child_name'+document.getElementById('child_name').value;
```

In this case you are assigning cn1 to the String `'child_name'` + the value of your child_name textbox... it will never equal an empty String.

Secondly, you'll want your `insert()` method to return `false` on error in order to stop the button's intended action.

Comment: "you'll want your insert() method to return false on error" -- Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: As Jim explains [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/128966/567090), returning false for an onclick will tell the browser that the default behavior (submitting the form, in your case) should not take place.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the function to this: (NOTE: you have to add more tests to the if clause for the rest of the elements)

```
function insert() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XLMHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }


    if (document.getElementById('child_name').value === '' ||
        document.getElementById('age').value === '' || 
        ...more tests... || 
        document.getElementById('zip').value === '') {
        alert ("Please enter all required fields.");
        return false;
    } else {
        cn1 = 'child_name'+document.getElementById('child_name').value;
        ag2 = 'age'+document.getElementById('age').value;
        hm3 = 'hometown'+document.getElementById('hometown').value;
        bg4 = 'boy_girl'+document.getElementById('boy_girl').value;
        fn5 = 'first_name'+document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        ln6 = 'last_name'+document.getElementById('last_name').value;
        email = 'email'+document.getElementById('email').value;
        ad8 = 'address1'+document.getElementById('address1').value;
        ad9 = 'address2'+document.getElementById('address2').value;
        ct10 = 'city'+document.getElementById('city').value;
        st11 = 'state'+document.getElementById('state').value;
        zp12 = 'zip'+document.getElementById('zip').value;

        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'payment.php', true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(cn1&ag2&hm3&bg4&fn5&ln6&email$ad8&ad9&ct10&st11&zp12); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still proceeds to the next page even with blank fields.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd give each one of those elements a common name or a class.

For example:

```
<input id="child_name" class="not_blank" type="text">
<input id="age" class="not_blank" type="text">
<input id="hometown" class="not_blank" type="text">
```

Since you are tying all those elements as a group by class.

Then your javascript would be a lot easier:

```
var flagInvalid = false;
var tempArray = document.getElementsByClassName("not_blank");
for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
{
    if (tempArray[i].value == "" || tempArray[i].value === undefined || tempArray[i].value == null){
        flagInvalid = true;
        break; 
    }
}

if (flagInvalid == false){
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'payment.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(cn1&ag2&hm3&bg4&fn5&ln6&email$ad8&ad9&ct10&st11&zp12); 

} else { alert ("Please enter all required fields."); }
```

Btw, I strongly advise not to use "alert". Try to create a messaging system on the document itself. Like:

```
<span id="log" class="hidden" style="color:red"><b>"Please enter all required fields." <b></span>
```

Your css would look like this:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
.show { display: inline; }
```

Your javascript would be changed to:

```
if (flagInvalid == false){
    var log = document.getElementById("log");
    log.className = 'hidden';
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'payment.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(cn1&ag2&hm3&bg4&fn5&ln6&email$ad8&ad9&ct10&st11&zp12); 

} else { 
    var log = document.getElementById("log");
    log.className = 'show';
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It still proceeds to the next page, even when the required fields are left blank.

Comment: You'd have to diagnose what value is being passed into tempArray[i].value. If it is not equal to "" then you might have to see if it is undefined or if it is null. I just updated the code above.