# JavaScript not firing in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 function isGoodEmail() {
            var email = document.getElementById("<%=txtComapnyEmail.ClientID%>").value;
            if (email == "Email") {
                if (window.isValidEmail(email)) {
                    if (/(aol|gmail|yahoo|hotmail)\.com$/.test(email)) {
                        alert(' valid email, but not for this site.  No free service emails!');
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Button code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" class="button-orange" Text="Confirm and start my company page"
                                ID="Companystart" OnClick="CompanystartClick" OnClientClick="isGoodEmail" />
```

I am calling the above JavaScript from the button, but it is not validating the email. Even if entered `gmail` it is accepted.

Comment: Based on your post, its "firing" exactly as you wrote it. Why would you think it would do anything if you typed `gmail` with `if(email=="Email")`? What is `window.isValidEmail`?

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" class="button-orange" Text="Confirm and start my company page"
                            ID="Companystart" OnClick="CompanystartClick" OnClientClick="return isGoodEmail()" />
```

Your are missing 'return' before your client click function call **OnClientClick="return isGoodEmail()"**

As you have written return true and false in your java-script so in your function call too there should be return before the function name.

For better understanding of **`return true and false`** you can go through this link

[What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event)

---EDIT

```
 function isGoodEmail() {
        alert("In the beginning");
        var email = document.getElementById("<%=txtComapnyEmail.ClientID%>").value;
        alert(email);
        if (email == "Email") {

            if (window.isValidEmail(email)) {
                if (/(aol|gmail|yahoo|hotmail)\.com$/.test(email)) {
                    alert(' valid email, but not for this site.  No free service emails!');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: <asp:Button runat="server" class="button-orange" Text="Confirm and start my company page"
                                    ID="Companystart" OnClick="CompanystartClick" OnClientClick="return isGoodEmail()" /> I have tried but script not working

Comment: put some alert in your java-script function and check weather it is calling that function or not?

Comment: why are you using **email == "Email"** and **window.isValidEmail(email)**

Comment: function isGoodEmail() {
                var email = document.getElementById("<%=txtComapnyEmail.ClientID%>").value;
                alert('Script entered');}  <asp:Button runat="server" class="button-orange" Text="Confirm and start my company page"
                                    ID="Companystart" OnClick="CompanystartClick" OnClientClick="return isGoodEmail()" /> I tried in the following to whether is firing script or not.It has not been working

Comment: can you change OnClientClick="return isGoodEmail()" to OnClientClick="javascript:alert('')" and check weather an alert is coming  or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `OnClientClick="return isGoodEmail()"` it will work it invokes JavaScript code.

but suppose you put "gmail" as text for email, then the if condition

```
if (email == "Email")
```

is false so nothing is executed inside or returned
hence it feels like JavaScript is not invoked

try using firebug to debug and break-point js code

Comment: function isGoodEmail() {
                var email = document.getElementById("<%=txtComapnyEmail.ClientID%>").value;
                alert('Script entered');}  <asp:Button runat="server" class="button-orange" Text="Confirm and start my company page"
                                    ID="Companystart" OnClick="CompanystartClick" OnClientClick="return isGoodEmail()" /> I tried in the following to whether is firing script or not.It has not been working