# PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0); restrict postback of all controls on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I want to avoid postback for following control  It works fine .
But when i click on that control ,all postback of other controls on the page also does not occur.Before click on following all works fine.

```
  <div class="close_but">
          <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEChartZoomClose" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/close.png" OnClientClick="javascript:zoomclosepopup();" PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0);" />
       </div>
```

I dont know what to do now .Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, 
remove `PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0);"`,
and add return false to OnClientClick :

```
<asp:ImageButton  OnClientClick="javascript:zoomclosepopup();return false;" ID="imgbtnEChartZoomClose" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/close.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .It works fine.will you explain me what return false makes sense

Comment: What sense do return false do

Comment: I think "return false" will tell browser stop doing things when event handle, it seems no document specification for this.
It has discussed here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event