# Javascript non-redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

How to stop a HTML page from redirecting using Javascript when the user clicks a link if a condition is false/true? To be specific, the link is something like this:

```
<a href = "something.html">
<li class ="num" id="day1" onclick = "return checkDate(1)"></li>
<li class ="num" id="day2" onclick = "return checkDate(2)"></li>
<li class ="num" id="day3" onclick = "return checkDate(3)"></li> 
</a>
```

In my javascript file, I'll have something like:

```
Function checkdate(a){
if(a = 3){ don't redirect }

}
```

Just I don't know what to put to and all the google results for the problem are confusing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WesleyMurch -- All OP's `li` tags are inside an anchor

Comment: @WesleyMurch -- I also wouldn't capitalize `Function` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkdate(a){
if(a == 3){ return false; }

}
```

Comment: The reason why this works is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function checkdate( a ) {
    // block
    if ( a == 3 )
       return false;

    // your code to redirect if a != 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First, your markup is invalid. `<li>` tags need a `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent. Also, you're declaring a `Function`. JavaScript is VERY case sensitive, you'll need to declare this as `function`. I would modify your HTML to:

```
<li class ="num" id="day1" onclick = "checkDate(1)"></li>
<li class ="num" id="day2" onclick = "checkDate(2)"></li>
<li class ="num" id="day3" onclick = "checkDate(3)"></li>
```

JS:

```
function checkdate(a){
    if (!a == 3) {
        //redirect
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest something here using an onUnload event, but I think the simpler solution here is to have the actual "linking" code be in the `<li>`'s onclick event. I'm not quite sure if the other suggestions here work - you will "cancel" the onclick event for the `<li>`, but not for the `<a>`.

Here's my try. If you're using JQuery or something, there are other ways you can shorten it.

```
function gotoSomething(num) {
    if (checkdate(num)) {
        window.location = "something.html";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href = "#">
<li class ="num" id="day1" onclick = "gotoSomething(1)"></li>
<li class ="num" id="day2" onclick = "gotoSomething(2)"></li>
<li class ="num" id="day3" onclick = "gotoSomething(3)"></li> 
</a>
```

Comment: Hm. If "return false" worked for other people, then I obviously did something wrong in my test - when I put that in, it wasn't preventing the link. I guess this one can be ignored.