# Dropdown menu, anchor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a dropdown menu and it works fine, except the anchor (`a href="#"`) does not work.

I think the script has something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone can help me please?

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="listMenu on">
        <a class="depth1" href="#">aaa</a>
        <div class="depth2Wrap">
            <ul class="depth2">
                <li><a href="b.html">bbb</a></li>
                <li><a href="c.html">ccc</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listMenu"><a class="depth1" href="d.html">ddd</a></li>   
</ul>
```

---

```
$(function($) { 
    var li = $('.menu>.listMenu');
    li.addClass('off');
    $('.menu .on').find('.depth2Wrap').show(); 

    $('.menu>.listMenu>a').click(function() {
        var myArticle = $(this).parents('.listMenu:first');
        if(myArticle.hasClass('off')){
            li.addClass('off').removeClass('on');
            li.find('.depth2Wrap').slideUp(100);
            myArticle.removeClass('off').addClass('on');
            myArticle.find('.depth2Wrap').slideDown(100);
            li.removeClass('fir_sele');
        } else {
            myArticle.removeClass('on').addClass('off');
            myArticle.find('.depth2Wrap').slideUp(100);
            li.removeClass('fir_sele');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following

```
 return false;
```

`return false` tells the browser not to complete the default action, which is following the link.

See [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event)