# Message box cant be displayed When run in IIS?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iis

I wants to display an OK/CANCEL message box. I have written like this.

```
   if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wants to Save the details ?  ", "Validate", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         // do something if "OK "
    }
```

it works locally well.. but on IIS shows an error " Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application."
please help.

Comment: `MessageBox` is a Windows GUI widget, not a browser widget. If you call it from the server, it's shown **on the server**, not on the visitor's browser. If you want to show a message box on the client side, you need to use HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Since you are developing a web application it is not recommended that you show a modal dialog. Instead you should be showing an confirm dialog using javascript.

Comment: ohh thankyou :) how is it do with javascript ? @ zneak  @ Vishweshwar Kapse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the effect I believe you are wanting, you'll want to use the Javascript `confirm()` function. It is typically used like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to save the details?')" id="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

This would, upon clicking the button, display a confirmation box that would stop the server OnClick event from firing if the user clicks No, Cancel, etc.

`OnClientClick` will render as an `onclick` event on the `<input>` tag. The rest is determined by the browser's handling of Javascript. See [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event) for more details on what the return value of the code in `OnClick` (`OnClientClick`) does.

Here's an example of the return values of confirm() using Chrome. For the first execution I had clicked Cancel.

[image: JS confirm() example in Chrome)]

Comment: Don't forget to close quotes and brackets ;)

Comment: For completeness, you might want to include OnClick handler for the button. That's missing currently!!

Comment: how will be the confirm() ??  @jdphenix

Comment: @ARATHY `OnClientClick` will render as an `onclick` event on the `<input>` tag. The rest is determined by the browser's handling of Javascript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event for more details on what the return value of the code in `OnClick` (`OnClientClick`) does.

Comment: function confirm() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save the details??") == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
   }       is it means when return true it will goes to onclick event automatically ??   @jdphenix

Comment: That is a quite verbose way of expressing it - it can be simply `return confirm('Are you sure you want to save the details?')`. The `return` works very similarly to `return` in C#, and the Javascript in `onclick` returning `false` to most browsers will keep the default behavior from occuring (i.e. NOT posting back).

Comment: Got the cut and clear solution from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Server-Side-Yes-No-Confirmation-Box-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36694/discussion-between-jdphenix-and-arathy)