# Table using a tag and spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a table using css and a combination of `<a>` tags with `<span>`s something like :

```
<a class='header'>
  <span>User ID</span>
  <span>Name</span>
  <span></span>
</a>
<a href='somesite.php'>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>Ofek</span>
  <span><button type="button" onclick="somefunc()">Add to Favourites</button></span>
</a>
```

the results looks something like that :

[image]

Now my problem is that when i click the button i still get redirected to somesite.php, and the function somefunc() never gets called, i seen somewhere that a button cant be nested inside a span, so whats the alternative to make this work? i want that whenever user click on the line it will redirected him to somesite.php, but not when he presses the button, then i only want the func somefunc() to be called.

Comment: can you please post a working fiddle?

Comment: You are allowed to use tables for tables by the way – there is 0 reason to replace a table with a hacked together version. The "don't use tables" mantra is only for layout, not for tabular data.

Comment: Also, you tagged this with jQuery, but didn't actually use it. Instead of onclick use `$('button').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault; somefunc(); } ) ;`

Comment: @RichBradshaw would it help?

Comment: @BeNdErR: Why must every JS question on this site have a "fiddle"? (Which is a meaningless request to someone who's never heard of jsfiddle.net.)

Comment: @t.niese yes if you click the row but not the button then it should redirect you to the href

Comment: @user2736012 it helps who wants to understand / answer the question.

Comment: @BeNdErR: What specifically did you not understand about the question? If something was unclear to you, you should ask that OP clarify it. If you just want to play with a demo, then you should make one for yourself.

Comment: @user2736012 that's the point. The question was clear, a fiddle would be useful 1) because it IS useful for me/who wants to help, 2) I think is fine to provide as much examples/demo as possible when asking a question. This will raise the probability to get an answer, in my opinion. cheers

Comment: @BeNdErR: Right. The question had no need for it. It was *you* that needed/wanted it. So if you want one, make one. Cheers.

Comment: @user2736012 We have a different opinion about that, no problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting a `button` element in an `a` element creates problems in handling events, and it is [forbidden](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) in HTML5 CR.

The simple way to avoid creating the problem is to separate the interactive elements:

```
<a href='somesite.php'>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>Ofek</span>
</a>
  <span><button type="button" onclick="somefunc()">Add to Favourites</button></span>
```

This would not be possible (as such) in the logical approach where you use `table` markup, but it’s simple if you are simulating a table with CSS so that cells are `span` elements (or, generally, phrase/inline/text-level elements).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `return false` to your `somefunc()` code:

```
function someFunc () {
    // your existent code
    return false;
}
```

and in HTML `onclick="return somefunc()"`. But I also recommend to **not** use `onclick` HTML attributes but to use:

```
$("button").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    somefunc();
    return false;
});
```

Read about [this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128923/1420197).

Comment: @OfekRon: You also need to add `return` to your `onclick`. `onclick="return somefunc()"`

Comment: @user2736012 doesnt work still, the function never gets called

Comment: @user2736012 yes it works, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A3DEq/1/. that's why fiddles are useful.

Comment: @OfekRon Thanks. I don't use to use `onclick` attributes. Updated my answer. It should work...

Comment: @BeNdErR: Your demo fails. I was talking about the question, which is very clear, and needs no demo to explain the issue.

Comment: @user2736012 updated the code, forgot to save the edits. see the new link > http://jsfiddle.net/A3DEq/1/

Comment: @OfekRon: If the function never gets called, then there's some other issue. Is the function globally defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind click event to the button then use `preventDefault()`:

**JS**

```
function somefunc(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hey");
}
document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener(
    'click', somefunc, false
);
```

**working fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/KRVUv/1/