# javascript object object on a href="javascript:..." call

Tags: javascript, object, onclick, href

I do have a simple script which is not working properly or as expected.

```
<script>
function modify_val(target, valeur)
{
    $(target).val(valeur)
}
</script>


<a href="javascript:modify_val('#type1','$row->movie2');">$row->movie2 ($row->counter relations)</a>
```

The javascript is working properly as the targeted input value is modified but the page is "redirected" after the click with a page containing:

```
[object Object]
```

Why is there a print ? I don't understand... The OnClick method behave the same. href or OnClick="javascript:$('#type1').val('$row->movie2');" also behave the same.

Do you have any idea ?

PS : the page is in https mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behaviour should take place as well.

```
<script>
function modify_val(target, valeur)
{
    $(target).val(valeur);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Change your HTML as. I would suggest you to use `onClick` attribute

```
<a href="#" onClick="return modify_val('#type1','$row->movie2');">$row->movie2 ($row->counter relations)</a>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zPVaW/1/)

Comment: Just returning false won't help if you don't do anything with the return value.

Comment: It's still discarding the return value. And you don't need to use `javascript:` in onclick.

Comment: @Juhana not necessarily.You can use  `javascript:` it simply evaluated expression.the only think you need to make sure is to return false.or you can even say `preventDefault `

Comment: @captain As I said, you don't *need* to use it. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href=\"javascript:$('#type1').val('$row->movie2'); void(0);\">
```

works... Guessing as Mate suggested that a return is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to stop the default action of the link by passing the event object and calling `preventDefault()` or simply returning `false` from your inline event handler.

```
function modify_val(target, valeur) {
    $(target).val(valeur)
    return false;
}
```

See this post for info on returning `false` from an inline event handler: [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event).

---

For the cleanest code, I'd recommend not using an inline event handler at all and simply use jQuery (which you seem to already have available) to install a click event handler and keep your code and HTML much more separate (generally considered a good practice).  jQuery also allows you to return `false` from the event handler to prevent the default behavior.

See this article on [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) for more info on keeping your HTML and Javascript separate.

Comment: wont simply `return false` do?