# My function doesn't work inside onclick function

Tags: javascript, function, animation, canvas, onclick

I try to write pendulum simulation with canvas. My goal is to change start angle by clicking on Animate button and stop one by clicking Stop. But **animate(a0deg)** and **clearInterval(id)** doesn't work inside onClick functions.

If I enter these functions to console everything is ok, it works fine (for example I can write **clearInterval(id);** and animation will stop and then **animate(new_a0deg)** and animation will begin with new start angle),
but
if I put this functions inside onClick events - its doesn't work. It's really strange. Any ideas how to fix it? Please help. Thank you.

By the way link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/pafoteku/2/edit (**Important**: in jsbin it works another way, not like in local html file. This is another one strange thing. After click on button everithing disappear).

**Problem here:**

```
document.getElementById("animate").onclick = function () {
    //alert('onClick begin');
    clearInterval(id); // < - This doesn't work
    a0deg = document.getElementById("angle").value;
    animate(a0deg); // < - This doesn't work
    //alert('a0deg = '+a0deg);
};

document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(id); // < - This doesn't work
};
```

Whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pendulum</title>

<style >
canvas {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <form >
      <label>
        Angle:
        <input type="text" id="angle" name="angle" value="80" />
      </label>
      <button  id="animate" >Animate</button>
      <button id="stop" >Stop</button>
    </form>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">

  <script>
var a0deg = document.getElementById("angle").value;     //a0deg start angle (deg)
var id = null; //id of setInterval

function animate(a0deg) { 

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var fps = 60;           //fps
    var f = 1000/fps;       //time between frames
    var t = 0;              //current time
    var l = 1;              //phisical length of pendulum

    var a0 = Math.PI*a0deg/180; //a0deg start angle (rad)

    var lCanvas = 300;      //pendulum length on canvas (px) 
    var g = 9.8 ;           //g

    function draw() {
        t += f / 1000;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(300, 0);

        var theta = a0 * Math.cos(t/(Math.sqrt(l/g)))/Math.exp(t/10); 
        ctx.rotate(theta);

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; /* нить */
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0); 
        ctx.lineTo(0, lCanvas);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath(); 

        ctx.beginPath();         /* груз */
        ctx.arc(0, lCanvas, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }  
    id = setInterval(draw , f);
}

animate(a0deg); 

document.getElementById("animate").onclick = function () {
    //alert('onClick begin');
    clearInterval(id);
    a0deg = document.getElementById("angle").value;
    animate(a0deg); 
    //alert('a0deg = '+a0deg);
};

document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(id);
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to reduce the code, take out all the parts that are not part of the problem. Make it easier for the users that want to to help you.

Comment: Also, have you opened a debugger (firebug etc.)? Do you see any errors? What web browser are you using and what version?

Comment: I've tried it in last versions of Chrome and FF. In debugger no any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/pafoteku/5/edit)

Use

```
<button type="button" id="animate">Animate</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="animate" value="Animate" />
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop" />
```

Note that unless you use `type="button"`, `<button>` elements can behave buggy in some browsers.

And in this case, they behave like a submit button, so they send the form, reloading the page.

Then, another way of avoiding that problem, could be using

```
button.onclick = function (e) {
    /* Click event handler */
    e && e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

Where `e.preventDefault` prevents sending the form. Note that old browsers, which don't support it, may need the nonstandard (DOM0) `return false`.

Comment: Thanks! But still not sure that understand e && e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();

Comment: @Vega That's a short way of `if(e && e.preventDefault){e.preventDefault();}`. You can just use `e.preventDefault()` if you don't care about old browsers throwing errors because they don't implement it.

Answer (score 4):

try add

```
return false;
```

at the end of your onclick code.

Comment: It works! Thank you! But why??? I've spent two days for understanding the reason and still don't understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event

Comment: You can see Oriol's answer. His answer is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to not use form buttons and skip all the browser/forms quircks. Make your own button and everything works fine. This are all the changes I made to your code:

```
<div id="animate" style="background-color: gray; cursor: pointer;">Animate</div>
<div id="stop"    style="background-color: gray; cursor: pointer;">Stop</div>
```

I'm sure you can add CSS styles and make them prettier.