# Prevent jumping to the second row after pressing Enter on a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a `<textarea>` that `onkeypress` ('Enter') sends a message in a live chat. The problem is that after pressing first time "Enter", the `textarea` field starts from the second input row.

How do I make the field reset or not taking "Enter" as a next row value?

Code:

```
<textarea disabled = "enabled"
onblur = "stopTyping();"
onfocus = "playTitleFlag=false; 
window.title='';"
onkeypress = "tryToSend(event);"
id = "chatmsg"
rows = "1"
cols = "1"
class = "chatmsg"></textarea>
```

And the `onkeypress` function:

```
function tryToSend(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode;

    if (key == "13") {
        sendMsg();
        return;
    }

    var msg = document.getElementById("chatmsg").value;

    if (trim(msg) != "") {
        typing();
    }
    else {
        stopTyping();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To cancel the default behaviour you should use `return false;`

see [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event)

---

To reset a textarea simply set its value to `""`. `document.getElementById(f).value = ""`;

---

P.S
Note that [event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.keyCode) return an integer