# where does the return of onclick="return false" go?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to understand something in this code:

```
<a id="btn_save" href="#" onclick="return false;" title="">Save</a>
```

Where does the return `onclick="return false;"` go to?

Comment: it goes to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/128966/2663825)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fr4m4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are disabling the default function of the click event  by returning false on click.

for example :

```
<a id="btn_save" href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return false;" title="">Save</a>
```

Even though the  points to google.com, when you click the link , it won't take you to google.com. i.e. the default action is returned false.

It's similar to `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Returning false from an event handler is a way of telling the browser that you want to prevent the default action associated with the link.