# Onclick destroys other function

Tags: javascript

When I try to add this line of code :

```
onclick="document.getElementById('part3').style.display='';return false;"
```

Into a link it disables the other function for some reason.. This is the code in which i would like to add the above code:

```
a href="javascript:DecreaseQuantity('PROD_VK_1.4')">
```

Works fine until i add the code, then only the onclick function works not the javascript part.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove `return false;`

Comment: Do not use inline events and the href....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event

Comment: What's the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<a href="javascript:DecreaseQuantity('PROD_VK_1.4')" onclick="doFunction()" />

function doFunction() {
    document.getElementById('part3').style.display='';
    return false;
}
```

or:

```
function doFunction() {
    if ($("#part3").css("display", "")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```