# Unable to Redirect to different page on click ? mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return to a different page on button click but i'm unable to achieve . It hits the controller action method(onclick) but the view remains the same & url in the browser remains unchanged  .

**Html:**

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Home", "Index")' "/>
```

Even when i keep `http://www.google.com` it doesnt seems to work .

am i missing anything important here

Comment: Try using `input type="button"...` instead.

Comment: holy jesus *it worked* . i tried <button>,<input> & mostly all ways about to break my pc . saved my pc David . any particluar reason ? please add as answer so i can mark it , cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `input` of type `submit` will try to submit a form. The JavaScript you have attached to that button will run but then immediately get "overridden" by the button trying to do something else. You can do a couple of things:

**Option 1:** Use a different type such as button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Home", "Index")' "/>
```

**Option 2:** Return `false` in your JavaScript, this prevents the default action from happening.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" 
    onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Home", "Index"); return false;' "/>
```

A nice description of preventing the default action from happening is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/128966/1663001).

Comment: Good to know something new & appreciate it .