# How to avoid screen automatic scrolling when display element is set to none

Tags: javascript, scroll, show-hide

I try to hide specific rows of a table when a specific cell is clicked. However the screen automatically scrolled to the top of the page when the target block of rows is hidden. The main Cell is clickable and allow to hide the following associated cells. My table is very big and they are multiple clickable cells.

Here is simple version of my code:

```
<tr id="Main1" onclick="hideTr(this.id)"><td><a href="#">Main1</a></td></tr>
    <tr class = "main1Tr"><td>Cell1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "main1Tr"><td>Cell2</td>
    </tr>
<tr id="Main2" onclick="hideTr(this.id)"><td><a href="#">Main2</a></td></tr>
        <tr class = "main2Tr"><td>Cell3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class = "main2Tr"><td>Cell4</td>
        </tr>

function hideTr(id){
if(id=="Main1"){
    loading = document.getElementsByClassName("main1Tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < loading.length; i++){
            display = loading[i].style.display;
            if(display ==  "none"){loading[i].style.display="";}
            if(display ==  ""){loading[i].style.display="none";}
        }
    }
if(id=="Main2"){
        loading = document.getElementsByClassName("main2Tr");
            for (var i = 0; i < loading.length; i++){
                display = loading[i].style.display;
                if(display ==  "none"){loading[i].style.display="";}
                if(display ==  ""){loading[i].style.display="none";}
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot [to `return false;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event) in your `onclick` handler (not inside `hideTr`, that won't work). That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to return false onclick
try onclick="hideTr(this.id);return false"

Comment: hashchange :Sorry , but I seem you answered the question when I type the same answer