# forEach callback does not execute with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hide odd rows</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:#8F9779;width:200px;height:30px;">
        </div>
        <hr style="width:200px" align="left">
        <table border="1" >
            <tr class="hide" >
                <td width="40" height="20">row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hide">
                <td width="40" height="20">row 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hide">
                <td width="40" height="20">row 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>
        <button type="button" name="HideRows">Hide Odd Rows</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="hideOddRows.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
/* hideOddRows.js */
document.querySelector('[name=HideRows]').onclick = hideRows;

function hideRows(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
    elements.forEach(function(element){
        element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
    return true;
}
```

---

As per debugging, callback function for each `element` of `elements` array is not executing on click event.

I consider `elements` as keyed collection, as shown below..

[image]

--

How to resolve this error?

Comment: `elements` has `nodelist` and `forEach` does not work with `nodelist`. Try `[].forEach.call(elements,function(item){});`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`forEach` is not included in the prototype of the array-like `HTMLCollection` object returned by `getElementsByClassName`.

An `HTMLCollection` instance is array-like, in that you can access elements by indexes, but it does not include all of the methods of an array, as you have discovered with `forEach`.

You can however manually call the method on the object by accessing the method from the `Array` prototype.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element){
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

Comment: What is the story about `return true`? You didn't use it. Is it a must to say `return true` in callback and event handlers? Can't I say `return 1` or `return 23`?

Comment: @overexchange In your case, it means allow the default behavior. I excluded it from my sample, as it's not directly related to the `forEach` issue. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/128966/3155639

Answer (score 2):

The `forEach` method is for arrays. It's not working because `.getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection.

To work around this, use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element){
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

or shorter:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
[].forEach.call(elements, function(element){
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding the shorter alternative, as it makes an unused array instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert `elements` to an array and then call forEach().

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
 elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements,0);
    elements.forEach(function(element){
        element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
```

fiddle  :https://jsfiddle.net/assx7hmh/

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code, here is my solution:

```js
function hideRows(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
  for(var key in elements) {
    if(elements.hasOwnProperty(key))
      elements[key].style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  return true;
}
```

You just need to loop through object because `forEach` just accept array.

Comment: See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630)

Comment: But using `for..in` adds an extra check of enumerability.