# JavaScript: onclick and return false

Tags: javascript

I'm using this in my HTML:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="preload('12345');return false;">Click</a>
```

It calls the function preload() on an external js-file and works fine so far.

But i have dozens of those links and would like to remove alle those "return false" and put only one directly inside the preload()-function in the js-file.

But it will always be ignored?! Does the "return false" really only work inside the onclick="..."?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function preload () {
    // some code
    return false;
}

<a href="#" onclick="return preload('12345');">Click</a>
```

or use `addEventListener`

For example:

```
<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('.link').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        // some code;

       e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Basically, to explain why it's like this, the contents of the onclick block are a function. Evaluated `false;` is valid (if silly) JavaScript, but basically JavaScript wanted you to actually `return false`.

Answer (score 5):

Putting `return false;` in the inline `onclick` attribute prevents the default behavior (navigation) from occurring. You can also achieve this by clobbering the `onclick` attribute in JavaScript (i.e. assigning the `.onclick` property to be a function that returns false), but that's frowned upon as old-fashioned and potentially harmful (it would overwrite any additional event listeners attached to that event, for example).

The modern way to prevent the `<a>` element's default click behavior from occurring is simply to call the `.preventDefault()` method of the triggering event from within the attached event listener. You can attach the listener the standard way, using `.addEventListener()`

Some examples:

```js
// this works but is not recommended:
document.querySelector(".clobbered").onclick = function() {
  return false;
};

// this doesn't work:
document.querySelector(".attached").addEventListener("click", function() {
  return false;
});

// this is the preferred approach:
document.querySelector(".attachedPreventDefault").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a href="/fake" onclick="return false;">If you click me, I don't navigate</a><br/>
<a class="clobbered" href="/fake">If you click me, I don't navigate</a>
<br/>
<a class="attached" href="/fake">If you click me, I navigate</a>
<br/>
<a class="attachedPreventDefault" href="/fake">If you click me, I don't navigate</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put it into the `preload` function and in the `onclick` event just put `return false` will work. Maybe you've tried this code?

```
<a href="#" onclick="return preload('12345');">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `return false` clause into the inline function:

```
<input onclick="yourFunction();return false;">
```

Answer (score -1):

I would maybe suggest not using onClick() and instead using similar jQuery.

Comment: jQuery eats too much kilobytes ;)

Comment: Haha. well, I have used onClick() before but was very limited in what I could do. But best of luck, afraid I'm all out of ideas.