# unexpected whole page refresh using p:commandButton

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am using below code to delete the row in `p:datatable`. If am using onclick method inside `p:commandbutton` tag it refresh whole page else its working fine. please Give me some solution.

```
<p:commandButton title="Delete Affiliation" immediate="true" process="@this"
    update="affiliationList" alt="Delete Affiliation" icon="ui-icon-trash"
    action="#{readAuthorDetailsbean.deleteSelectedAffiliation}" style="width:30px"
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, Do you want to delete this record?');">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{affiliation}" 
        target="#{readAuthorDetailsbean.selectedAffilliationListAL}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: How is this javascript or jquery related? How do you want us to try to reproduce? Please show an [mcve]. Most likely you return something from the action

Comment: View full code. I add onclick(Java script function). It return true when i click yes in delete confirmation. It refresh whole page .

Comment: By default PrimeFaces adds `return false;` (because of ajax) to generated html code from `p:commandButton` component so it won't trigger form submission . If you add `confirm()` to `onclick` then after user clicks 'OK' the returned value is `true` and form submission occurs (normal post submit, not ajax - hence page refresh). You could try [`p:confirmDialog`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rephrase your `onclick` attribute to
`if (!confirm('Are you sure, Do you want to delete this record?')) return false;`
then it should work as expected. What it does is:

- if user confirms it doesn't return a value and PrimeFaces can further process AJAX request
- if user cancels confirmation then returned value is `false` and further processing is aborted.

If you just do `return confirm('Are you sure?')` and user is sure, the returned `true` value cancels PrimeFaces added `return false` at the end of the `onclick` attribute (it does that for ajax) and instead of ajax request you see normal post submission (page reload).
[`return false` cancels default behavior of html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-click-event-listener).

Comment: This is fixed in the upcoming 6.0 release (and most likely a 5.3.x one too). See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1349