# JavaScript confirm cancel does not work on Laravel Form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel

I have this confirm:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDelete() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

and then I have my Laravel form:

```php
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Test\\TestController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'onsubmit' => 'ConfirmDelete()']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I’m getting the message and if I’m pressing on OK, the thread gets deleted, but that also happens on cancel. What can I do so that nothing happens, if I’m pressing cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further tidy up your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDelete() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    }
</script>
```

Also, you need to make sure you return the function's response onsubmit, for example

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Test\\TestController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()']) !!}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot man! -- little other question, the output don't looks so well... is there a way to costum the output? like with a class or bootstrap?

Comment: The confirm alert that is shown is built into the browser so there's no way to style it (that I'm aware of). An alternative would be to use a custom modal, for example, please see the a bootstrap confirmation example: https://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Test\\TestController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add return statement before function call**.

Change the following code

```
'onsubmit' => 'ConfirmDelete()'
```

to

```
'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()'
```

You could also inline it, if you want ;)

```
'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")'
```

When calling a JavaScript function in an `onclick` event handler, [the return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behavior should take place as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-click-event-listener).

That's the reason why it is getting deleted even when you press `Cancel` from your confirm dialog.

Comment: thanks! works good too :) other question, do you have an idea how I can change the design output with maybe bootstrap? cause the output don't look so good

Comment: You cannot. You can imitate it by using CSS & JS. There are plenty of scripts/plugins that handle it pretty well using bootstrap or other styling frameworks http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/confirm-box