# How can i change the PHP value in textbox through Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a textbox the value load from PHP Here is the code

```
<input  type="text" id="fName" value="<?php echo $row['fName']; ?>" disabled/>
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="changeValue('fName')" />
```

my Javascript

```
function changeValue(id){  
var value = "test";
document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```

As soon as I click the function, the value change for a few second and go back to default one from database. Can anyone help me

Comment: Is that `input` element inside a `form`?

Comment: that id is parameter in function.. the code can run show the output but less than 1 second it willgo back to the value of database

Comment: your page must be refreshing or your data must be fetched and your form is updated with values from the database, are you using ajax in anyway like for eg. constant sync

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it is not inside the form

Comment: @EkaLeonardo It is inside a `form`, it's not possible to have that behaviour unless it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After clicking on the button, the page will reload so that the value of the database will be restored.

Please change

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="changeValue('fName')" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="changeValue('fName'); return false;" />
```

to avoid submitting the form.

For more information, please have a look at this: [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-click-event-listener)

Answer (score 0):

If you click on elements like links (`a` element) or buttons (`input[type="button"]` or `button`) page will be redirect. So at the end of `onClick` action you must write `return false` to force say to the browser **I don't want to redirect this page after click!**

For example:

```
function changeValue(id){
    var value = "test";

    document.getElementById(id).value = value;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i change the PHP value in textbox through Javascript

An alternative to using `document.getElementById(id).value` would be:

```
function changeValue(id){  
      var value = "test";
      document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("value", value);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add explanation of what you code is doing and why and how it answers the OP's question.