# not able to show jsf hidden panelGroup using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am trying show a *hidden panelGroup(**LAYOUT=BLOCK**)* on a button click.This my jsf code:

```
 <h:form id="userSetup" >
                    <h:inputText id="skills" a:placeholder="Skills" class="cff-inputText"></h:inputText>
                <br/><br/>
               //when user clicks this button div is shown
                <button class="cff-button"  onclick="toggleCertificateInput('#{certificateInput.clientId}',true)">Add Certificate</button>
                <br/><br/>
                //div to show on button click
                <h:panelGroup id="certificate-input"  layout="block" binding="#{certificateInput}" a:hidden="true">
                    <h:inputText value="#{uploader.certificateName}" class="cff-inputText" a:placeholder="Certificate Name"></h:inputText>
                    <h:inputText value="#{uploader.certificateLink}" class="cff-inputText" a:placeholder="Link"></h:inputText>
                    <h:commandButton value="Save Certificate" class="cff-button" action="#{uploader.saveCertificate()}">
                        <f:ajax  execute="@form" ></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>


            </h:form>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
//if toggle is true then show the div else hide it
function toggleCertificateInput(inputDivId,toggle){

  inputDiv = document.getElementById(inputDivId);

        if(toggle){
            alert("about to display input div");
          inputDiv.style.display = "block";          
        }else{
            alert("about to hide input div");
          inputDiv.style.display = "none";
        }

}
```

The div show for a second and then hidden. I am using ajax. Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Try adding `return false`, so `onclick="toggleCertificateInput('#{certificateInput.clientId}',true);return false"`

Comment: Thankyou its working! can you please explain what happend when return false was added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `onclick` attribute of a button to run some JavaScript. However, since your `onclick` handler does not return `false`, the default action of clicking a button (submitting a form) is also executed. To prevent this behavior, simply add `return false` to your handler.

See also:

- [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-click-event-listener)