# Show / hide php mysql results with loader

Tags: php, css, mysql, hide, show

I have MySQL database results.

I want to show 3 rows and then hide rest.

When the user clicks to load more data then to appear all rows.

The problem is when I click show more, then only one more row appears.

```
<?php
$query_brands = mysql_query("SELECT distinct pd_filter1 from tbl_brands2 WHERE pd_code in (select pd_code from tbl_product where cat_id='2')") or die(mysql_error());
$count_brands  = mysql_num_rows($query_brands);
  if($count_brands > 0) {
  while($fetch_brands = mysql_fetch_array($query_brands)) {
    $record_brands[] = $fetch_brands;
  }
  }

$i_brands=0;
foreach($record_brands as $records_brands) {                                
?>
<table border="1" width="215" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;" bgcolor="#eeeff0">
  <tr>
    <td>
<?php
      $i_brands = $i_brands + 1;
      if ($i_brands > 3)
        {
?>
        <div id="myDIV_Filter1_1" style="display:none";>
<?php
        }
      }
?>
    <div id="myDIV_Filter1_2">
      <span class="class22">
        <a href="#" onclick="myFunction();return false;">show more...</a>
      </span>
    </div>  

    <div id="myDIV_Filter1_3" style="display:none";>
      <span class="class22">
        <a href="#" onclick="myFunction();return false;">show less...</a>
      </span>
    </div>  

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
    var x_filter1_1 = document.getElementById("myDIV_Filter1_1");
    var x_filter1_2 = document.getElementById("myDIV_Filter1_2");
    var x_filter1_3 = document.getElementById("myDIV_Filter1_3");
    if (x_filter1_1.style.display === "none") {
        x_filter1_1.style.display = "block";
        x_filter1_2.style.display = "none";
        x_filter1_3.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x_filter1_1.style.display = "none";
        x_filter1_2.style.display = "block";
        x_filter1_3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: if i want to change the current code, u see any error?

Comment: on js code : onclick="myFunction();

Comment: i dont think thats the problem, because when i click show more i can see more data . the problem is i can see only one row instead of 3 rows. there is something wrong with php mysql while

Comment: then use var_dump($record_brands); after the mysql while to see if the query is throwing the results as expected

Comment: i understand , i got stuck in this point

Comment: if i echo $count_brands here : <div id="myDIV_Filter1_1" style="display:none";>
          <?php
          echo $i_brands; i take only number =4, i lost 5,6 etc values

Comment: 6 rows in the point u asked me

Comment: the first div display none is to hide results more than 3 rows, and the other div display none is the click link to hide data. i think the point is on loop, it stops on 4 rows. sorry i have to go, we will continue it tomorrow. thanks

Comment: hello have u test it?

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors on your code:

1) Try not to use **return** the way you are using right now in code lines like this one:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction();return false;">show more...</a>
```

You can use it better like it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener)

2) You have all your divs of the code example in **display none**, the user will never see the information in those divs because you don't have any code to start showing some of them. In the same line you put a ";" after the style but it must  be inside the style. This line has an error:

```
<div id="myDIV_Filter1_3" style="display:none";>
```

It must be this way:

```
<div id="myDIV_Filter1_3" style="display:none;">
```

The "show-hide" logic on your **javascript** function myFunction has an error because your div **id="myDIV_Filter1_1"** contains the other 2 div you have on your code example so **you can't hide this particular div** because you will lose the "show" or "hide" of the other 2 divs. That way it'll never show you the other 3 rows you wanted to see. I fixed all the errors you can check the code on my snippet here:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x_filter1_1 = document.getElementById("myDIV_Filter1_1");
    var x_filter1_2 = document.getElementById("myDIV_Filter1_2");
    var x_filter1_3 = document.getElementById("myDIV_Filter1_3");
    if (x_filter1_3.style.display === "none") {
        x_filter1_1.style.display = "block";
        x_filter1_2.style.display = "none";
        x_filter1_3.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x_filter1_1.style.display = "block";
        x_filter1_2.style.display = "block";
        x_filter1_3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<?php
$query_brands = mysql_query("SELECT distinct pd_filter1 from tbl_brands2 WHERE pd_code in (select pd_code from tbl_product where cat_id='2')") or die(mysql_error());
$count_brands  = mysql_num_rows($query_brands);
  if($count_brands > 0) {
  while($fetch_brands = mysql_fetch_array($query_brands)) {
    $record_brands[] = $fetch_brands;
  }
  }

$i_brands=0;
foreach($record_brands as $records_brands) {                                
?>
<table border="1" width="215" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;" bgcolor="#eeeff0">
  <tr>
    <td>
<?php
      $i_brands = $i_brands + 1;
      if ($i_brands > 3)
        {
?>
        <div id="myDIV_Filter1_1">
<?php
        }
      }
?>

    <div id="myDIV_Filter1_2" >
      <span class="class22">
        <a href="#" onclick="myFunction();">show more...</a>
      </span>
    </div>  

    <div id="myDIV_Filter1_3" style="display:none">
      <span class="class22">
        <a href="#" onclick="myFunction();">show less...</a>
      </span>
    </div>  

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for answer, the only change u told me is to remove return false; from a href. let me ask your question, when the webpage opens then the user can see the first 3 rows, then it comes the if ($i_brands > 3)
          {
          ?>
          <div id="myDIV_Filter1_1" style="display:none;">
          <?php
          } and then the rest rows should disappeared. thats why myDIV_Filter1_1 is on display none. the point is the user can see first rows only and when click show more to see other rows. so i need help in that because only 3+1 rows appears

Comment: also let me continue, this code (with the errors u told me) its working with no mysql data. i think the problem is on php loop, but i cant find it