# How to use "return false;" in Javascript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering about the use of `return false;` because…

⋅ Sometimes I see functions like that:

```
function foo(){
  ⋅⋅⋅
  return false;
}
```

⋅ Sometimes I see the calling of functions like that:

```
<div onclick="foo(); return false;"></div>
```

⋅ Sometimes I see **both** of the above,

⋅ Sometimes I see **none** of the above.

(I know about the topic [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener), but that seems to answer only to my point #2, or am I wrong?)

So I ended up with questions about it.
What is the *right way* to use `return false;`?
And when is it *necessary* to do so?

When using jQuery, is the *right way* or the *necessity* modified ?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener)

Comment: Depends very much on what you want to do. In jQuery it can be used to break out of an `each`, in that html snippet it is used to not do anything else after `foo` on click, in the function it just returns false.

Comment: You can use the html way then you don't need to return false from the function. Or return false from the function and in the html just return the value you get from the function, which is false.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use inline event in javascript!

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina, Thank you for your comment. Is it considered bad practice only for the fact that the JS should be entirely at the same place?

Comment: Does someone know why my question was downvoted? So that I could correct it, if necessary.

Comment: @TakitIsy, if you use JS event, use it into your js script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an old-style `onxyz`-attribute event handler (commonly called "DOM 0" because they're not specified), returning `false` prevents the default action (more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener)). For instance, for a link, it prevents following the link; for a form's `onsubmit`, it prevents form submission.

So there are multiple answers to your "what's the correct way" question:

- If you want the function `foo` to determine whether the default action occurs, use `onclick="return foo()"` and have `foo` return `false` to prevent the default, or return anything else (or just `return;`, which will effectively return `undefined`) to allow it.
- If you *always* want the default prevented, use `onclick="foo(); return false;"` (although that will fail to prevent the default if `foo` throws an exception).
- On any vaguely-modern browser, if you always want the default prevented even if `foo` throws an exception: `onclick="event.preventDefault(); foo();"` (yes, this even works on Firefox, which doesn't have the global `event` variable — because `onxyz` handlers execute in a scope with a local `event` variable).

But perhaps mostly:

- Old-style "DOM 0" handlers are generally not best practice; instead, use modern event handling (`addEventListener`, `attachEvent` if you need to support obsolete IE versions).

Take your choice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, I do not recommend inline JavaScript.

You should use `addEventListener`.

**Example :**

```
document.getElementById('yourdiv').addEventListener('click', function(){
  foo(); 
  return false;
});
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('yourdiv').addEventListener('click', function(){
  foo(); 
});
```

with `function foo() { return false }`

depending on your needs

**First case :**

```
function foo() {
  return false;
}
```

The function `foo` is called, and this very function returns `false`. So you can get the false by doing :

`var isitfalse = foo()` --> `isitfalse` will be defined to `false`

OR

```
if (!isitfalse) {
   alert('Yes it\'s false')
}
```

**Second case :**

`<div onclick="foo(); return false;"></div>`

The action `onclick` will call the `foo` function, then `onclick` will call `return false`. So it's different from the first case where it's your function that returns `false`

**jQuery**

`return false` or `return true` or `return what-ever-you-want` works the same in jQuery, same way to use it

**Other thing to know :**

If you ask a function to return anything, the function won't go further.

```
function foo() {

  if (2 > 1) { return something }

  alert()

}
```

In this case, you'll never see the alert

Answer (score -1):

Functions with no explicit return value will always return `undefined`.
In case of event handlers, you return false to avoid the default browser behavior. See [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener)