# No default spaces between the texts in the input fields of an HTML CSS form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created an html css form and for the layout of the website i used javascript and jquery but currently i am not being able to add a space while filling anything on the contact form.
the contact form can be found at the bottom of this page or you can click on CONTACT in the navbar [www.avanishkumar.in](http://www.avanishkumar.in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `eventListeners` for various keys. I guess this is the code that is not allowing you to use space bar as the keycode of space bar is `32`. In your game.js file.

```
        case 32:
            return false;
        break;
```

Here is the key mapping
http://www.steveharrell.com/computer/ascii.htm

```
        case 32:
            return true;
        break;
```

Return `true` instead for the spacebar to work. This will not prevent the default action of the browser.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/128966/8252164