# On toggle change top position JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have a div that on click it expands or closes, I would also like to change the top position of a different fixed div depending on the click state of the original div.

**For example**
If original div is expanded I would like div 2 to have `top:10px`

If closed div 2 to have `top:0`

**This is the current toggle function to expand or close the div**

```
<a href="#" class="toggle" onclick="dropDownMSG(); this.parentNode.classList.toggle('open');return false;">
                    <img src="/Static/images/header-logo-top.png" alt="Informa logo"/>
                </a>
```

**then bellow I have**

```
function dropDownMSG() {
         document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.top = "10";
    }
```

However this only adds `top:10px` on click, so on toggle again that closes the div the `top` dose not reset to `0`.

I need a way to say:

that if toggle open then

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.top = "10";
```

Else

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.top = "0";
```

Comment: you can add a callback to your toggle function like `.toggle(speed,easing,callback)`

Comment: _“However this only adds top:10px on click”_ - no it doesn’t, it only tries to set the invalid value `10`. All length values in CSS _require_ a unit, unless the value happens to be zero.

Comment: Ok thanks @ArunKumar, ill try this. +1

Comment: @misorude thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check current top value in an if else block and update accordingly

```
function dropDownMSG() {
    const element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    if (element.style.top === '10') {
        element.style.top = '0';
    } else {
        element.style.top = '10';
    }
}
```

For better performance, I'd advise you to use a classes.

```
function dropDownMSG() {
    const element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    //        if (element.style.top === '10') {
    //            element.style.top = '0';
    //        } else {
    //            element.style.top = '10';
    //        }

    if (element.className.indexOf('expand') === -1) {
        element.className += 'expand';
    } else {
        element.className = element.className.replace('expand', '');
    }
}
```

and add a css class

```
.expand{top:10px;}
```

Comment: Hmm kinda fixes one but brakes the other. the second div now adds top and removes top. perfect but now the main div dose not expand on click.

Comment: Yes. But, I think you can move that code also to **dropDownMSG()** function. Also, I think you can replace return with `event.preventDefault()` like this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/128966/6762052)

Comment: will try and let you know.

Comment: Also, don't forget to bind this in anchor tag like this `<a href="#" class="toggle" onclick="dropDownMSG.bind(this)(event)">`

Answer (score 1):

use html data-attribute to assign the state then change it on your script on click.

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#" class="toggle" onclick="dropDownMSG(this)">
   <img src="/Static/images/header-logo-top.png" alt="Informa logo"/>
 </a>
```

**CSS**

```
  function dropDownMSG(elem){
    if(elem.dataset.state === "open"){
      elem.dataset.state = "close";
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.top = "10px";
    }
    else{
      elem.dataset.state = "open";
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.top = "0";
    }
  }
```

Comment: oww I forgot to add units.. see update `document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.top = "10px";`