# Javascript opens duplicate tabs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following link that when clicked, opens a new tab and refreshes the page with the link in.
It works fine in Safari and Chrome but opens duplicate tabs in Firefox.

```
<a href="../print_letters/letter.php" class="button success" target="_blank" onClick="openWindowReload(this)">Run Letters</a>

function openWindowReload(link) {
var href = link.href;
window.open(href,'_blank');
location.href = 'index.php' + "?welcome_letters=export&welcome_letters=export"
}
```

Any ideas why Firefox is doing this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't stop the default behavior.
Could you call `preventDefault` on the click event?

Comment: @ farvilain Can you tell me how I would apply preventDefault to my code please?

Comment: From my understanding, this stops the parent page from refreshing. I need the parent page to refresh. The issue I have is that Firefox opens two tabs instead of just one. Safari and Chrome only open one tab which is correct.

Comment: `return false;` at the end of the function could help. There is a thread about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener. If not, I'll try tomorrow with Firefox. not on my personnal laptop right now :(

Comment: return false; stopped 2 tabs being opened but unfortunately it also stopped the parent page from being refreshed.