# How do I disable an <a> tag link for a certain child of an element?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a container, which leads to the other page when I click it. However, I want some elements inside this container to be disabled, so when I click on them the link won't work. How do I do that?


For example, here I want to disable the red side of the container.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3e3e3e;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.block-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block-1">Active</div>
    <div class="block-2">Disabled</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One option would be to add a click handler. Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener) talks about, you can tell the browser to follow or not to follow the link by calling `e.preventDefault()`.

In the code below, change `disabled` and you turn on/off the link.

I should add, though, that while I am not an accessibility expert, this is not very "semantic" and I'm guessing probably doesn't work well with screen readers... Maybe something like `aria-disabled` could be used to fix that, but I'm not familiar enough with it to say.

```js
var link = document.querySelector('a');
var disabled = true;
link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (disabled) {
    console.log('disabled');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">My link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything you put in `<a>` tag will be clickable, because "click" event is triggered actually on parent (`<a>` tag) and not on what's inside it.

You need to separate this - simply make one div a link and another not.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3e3e3e;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.block-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <a href="#" class="block-1">Active</a>
   <div class="block-2">Disabled</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although It's not very suitable if there is hundreds of these blocks. I thought maybe there is a more elegant way to just disable some of them

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title>Disable Link using CSS</title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .not-active { 
            pointer-events: none; 
            cursor: default; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <center> 
        <h1 style="color: green;">GeeksforGeeks</h1> 
        <h3>A Computer Science Portal for Geeks</h3> 
        <b>Disabled link:</b> To visit us  
          <a href="www.geeksforgeeks.org"
             class="not-active">Click Here</a> 
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <b>Enabled link:</b> To use our ide  
          <a href= 
             "https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tryit.php"> 
            Click Here</a> 
    </center> 
</body> 
  
</html>
```