# Why does console.log returns correctly but my function returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I dont get why this function's console.log returns the value, and the typeof correctly, but its return value is invalid to use in another function

I'm attempting to use bubble event to collect the value of the clicked button.

```
<DIV class = "keys">
        <button class = "key" id = "rock" value = "rock">Rock</button>
        <button class = "key" id = "paper" value = "paper">Paper</button>
        <button class = "key" id = "scissors" value = "scissors">Scissors</button>
</DIV>
```

Here is the JS:

```
const bubbleBar = document.querySelector(".keys");
bubbleBar.addEventListener("click", playerPlay);
bubbleBar.addEventListener("click", display);

function playerPlay(e){
            let playerChoice = ""
            console.log(e.target.value); //debugs correctly
            playerChoice = e.target.value;
            console.log(playerChoice, typeof playerChoice); //debugs correctly
            return playerChoice; // apparently returns nothing
        }

function display(){
            console.log(playerPlay) // displays function playerPlay(e), not the result of the first function.
        }
```

Comment: `// apparently returns nothing` It does return your value, but you're not using it. Returning a value inside an event handler has no impact _(well, in this case)_. I guess you meant to make it a global variable instead, so that your `display` function can access it later. Move your `let playerChoice = "";`  at the top of your code, and remove the useless `return` statement

Comment: ... and replace `console.log(playerPlay)` with `console.log(playerChoice)`, in your `display` function

Comment: More importantly, the return value from an event handler determines whether or not the event continues to be processed. Return `true` from the event handler and the event will continue with the default browser behavior on the clicked element; return `false` and the behavior will be cancelled. Returning `playerChoice` as a String will always be _truthy_ so processing will continue. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/128966/17300)

Comment: @blex thank you very much. It worked. Garrett Motzner answer, as well, helped a lot. "the useless return statatement" was the part I was getting stuck at, and now I learned about functions with side effects. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, returning a value from an event handler doesn't do anything with that value. The value is used to determine further event processing.

If you want the value you will have to store it somewhere from within the handler.
This code saves the value in a global variable `chosenValue` and also sets the value as the text within a `<span>` — what you actually do to store the value will depend on how you plan to make use of the value later.

```js
let chosenValue;
const bubbleBar = document.querySelector(".keys");
bubbleBar.addEventListener("click", playerPlay);
bubbleBar.addEventListener("click", display);

function playerPlay(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let playerChoice = ""
  console.log(e.target.value); //debugs correctly
  playerChoice = e.target.value;
  console.log(playerChoice, typeof playerChoice); //debugs correctly
  document.getElementById('playerChoice').innerText = playerChoice;
  chosenValue = playerChoice;
  console.log(`chosenValue variable value is now ${chosenValue}`);
}

function display(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="keys">
  <button class="key" id="rock" value="rock">Rock</button>
  <button class="key" id="paper" value="paper">Paper</button>
  <button class="key" id="scissors" value="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
<div>
  Player's Choice: <span id="playerChoice">none</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, @Stephen, I'm sorry but I don't understand, at the moment, why do I need to e.preventDefault()... I saw your comment above and what do you mean by: "the return value from an event handler determines whether or not the event continues to be processed."  In this case, what continues to be processed since its truthy?

Comment: @LeonardoNobreGhiggino - whether or not you need to call `e.preventDefault()` depends on what is being clicked. If you have a link or a button and you attach a click handler to it, that link or button still wants to perform its natural action — follow a link or submit a form — unless you tell it _not_ to perform its _default_ behavior. If you add a handler to, for example, a `<div>` there is no default behavior so you don't have to preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

### A note on scope and return statements

Nested scopes can often be confusing, and where things return to isn't always clear. Here's some examples fo reference:

```js
function simple(){ return 'foo' }
```

Returns `"foo"` when `simple` is called like `simple()`
(or `simple("args", "aren't", "used", "but still are passed")` or `simple.call()`)

---

```js
function nested(){
  return function inner(){
    return 'foo'
  }
}
```

`nested`, when called, returns a function, but that function does not run immediately. so to get `"foo"` you would need to call it like this:

```js
let outerResult = nested() // creates and returns a function
outerResult() // returns "foo"

//or more concisely
nested()() // calls both functions in order.
```

Here we see that `return` is always going to return to the function it is "closest" too, the inner-most function. `return` can't skip out of the function it is in.

---

```js
function loop(){
  let values = [1,2,3]

  for (let value of values){
    return value
  }
}
```

Returns `1`, and the loop does not run another time. So in this case the block does not change the scope of return.

---

```js
function callbackLoop(){
  let values = [1,2,3]

  values.forEach(value => { return value })
}
```

This code has a bug. You might expect that this code would work the same as the regular loop, but it doesn't, and in fact, it can't. There is no way for the return in the function `value => { return value }` to cause the `callbackLoop` function to return. It can only return itself, same as the `nested` example. Sometimes functions that take callbacks will pass along the callback return value, but they don't have to if they don't want to. Since [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is designed for side effects (functions that don't have return values) it doesn't do this, and neither does [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), because it also is designed for side effects.

An example of a function that takes a "pure function" callback, instead of side effects, is [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const result = [1, 4, 9, 16].map(x => {return x * 2});
// `map` returns: [2, 8, 18, 32] 
// (it gets the return value of the callback function for 
// each item in the array, and uses that)
```

A "pure function" is a function that operates on only the inputs (`x`) in this case, and makes no changes to any variables. Multiplication "creates" a new value, and that is what is returned. The original `x` is not "mutated" (it is left unchanged). In order for pure functions to be useful, they need to return a value, and that value needs to be used in some way.

Comment: Thanks, Garrett, for the detailed explanation. I learned a lot from it. Now I need to understand a when a function is designed for side effects. Just learned those exist.


May I ask one other thing: I realize it is the side effect that is changing the global variable from within the function. When will I know that will happen, or wont happen? How can foresee it?

Comment: Any function in javascript _can_ have side effects, even if it does have a return value. The example you mentioned is a common side effect: changing a value that exists outside of the function. But I think what you want to know is if you _need_ to use a side effect with a function, or if the return value will be respected. To determine that, you need to check the documentation and examples (or maybe the source code) for the function that uses the "callback" function that you provide. As a rule of thumb though, callback functions generally do need side effects to do anything useful.