# Why am I unable to select an item in a dropdown?

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following MRE code that is mean to select `EU Odds` from a dropdown:

```
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_driver = str(Path("chromedriver/chromedriver/"))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/tennis/")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-header-oddsformat-expander").click()
sleep(1)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
target = "EU Odds"
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[.='" + target + "']"))).click()
```

Everything works up until the final line which doesn't make the selection. If I try to do this manually on the page that chromedriver opens then I'm also unable to make the selection. However, if I open up a normal browsing window then I am able to make the selection.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Even if I open the site manually, I can’t make a new selection or some selection other than `EU Odds`. It always reloads the page with the same option. Are you sure there is nothing wrong with the website itself?

Comment: @Jarvis - hey. I think you've figured out the issue indirectly. It looks like they've changed the site so you can only change the odds if you're logged in...

Comment: I see, guess I should have posted this as my answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue is with the website itself. Trying to select any other option other than `EU Odds` doesn’t work even manually. Seems like you need to be logged in to do that.

Comment: I think it’s doing some IP-based filtering and setting up a country based on location. Try with VPN for EU country while running script and that dropdown will default to `EU Odds`-not the perfect solution but workaround

Answer (score 1):

From a broader perspective there is nothing wrong in your code.

However to optimize your code you may like to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` for the expander to be clickable.
- The texts *EU Odds*, *UK Odds*, *US Odds*, etc are not exactly within the `<li>` but within it's grand parent `//li/a/span`
- So to select *EU Odds*, *UK Odds*, *US Odds* one by one your optimized [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) can be:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/tennis/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "user-header-oddsformat-expander"))).click()
  target = "EU Odds"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a/span[text()='" + target + "']"))).click()
  time.sleep(3) # for visual demonstration
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "user-header-oddsformat-expander"))).click()
  target = "UK Odds"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a/span[text()='" + target + "']"))).click()
  time.sleep(3) # for visual demonstration
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "user-header-oddsformat-expander"))).click()
  target = "US Odds"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a/span[text()='" + target + "']"))).click()
  ```

---

### This usecase

However even sucessfully clicking on the options with text as **EU Odds**, **UK Odds**, **US Odds** doesn't changes the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). Now if you look into the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) the expander class itself is having the value as `user-header-fakeselect-options`. Additionally, the `onclick` attribute of the `//li/a/span` items are having **`return false;`**.

[image: fakeselect]

As per the discussion [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to a click event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener) **`return false;`** does three separate things when called:

- Calls `event.preventDefault();`
- Calls `event.stopPropagation();`
- Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

Hence selecting either of the dropdown options doesn't fires the `onclick` event and the *HTML DOM* remains unchanged.

---

### Conclusion

Possibly the DOM would change as per the `onclick` events when a authenticated user performs the selection after loggind in within the [website](https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/tennis/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Selenium has a special way to handle dropdown selection

First import select :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Then assign the dropdown to a variable:

```
dropdown_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exam_id"]')
```

Then create an object:

```
dropdown_object = Select(dropdown_element)
```

Finally select the option:(there will be a value for every options)

```
dropdown_object.select_by_value('17')
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out! I'm not sure what element I should be searching for in this line; `browser.find_element_by_xpath(<what goes here?>)`. I've tried `'//*[@id="user-header-oddsformat-expander"]'` which was what I clicked on before but I get the following error: `Select only works on <select> elements, not on <a>`. I can't find a `<select>` element in the HTML for the dropdown?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the website to your question and highlight the dropdown

Comment: Hi. The website address is `https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/tennis/`

Comment: Just to add to this. Selenium clicks on the dropdown successfully using this line: `driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-header-oddsformat-expander").click()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the xpatי:
Too many apostrophes around the text
Trying to locate the wrong tag, the clickable element is the `<a>` tag, not the `<li>` tag.

Use `"//a[.=' + target + ']"`